# BindingResolutionException while creating services to access database

Tags: laravel, models

We are trying to implement architecture suggested in following article in order to make our application extensible

http://dfg.gd/blog/decoupling-your-code-in-laravel-using-repositiories-and-services

The article divides the models into following

- Entities - normal Eloquent classes
- Repositories - these use Entities to get data
- Services - Contain Business logic

To try out the architecture we are trying to access a small table

We have created following classes

- app/models/entities/Reminder.php   //normal Eloquent model
- app/models/repositories/reminder/ReminderInterface.php
- app/models/repositories/reminder/ReminderRepository.php
- app/models/repositories/reminder/ReminderRepositoryServiceProvider.php
- app/models/services/reminder/ReminderFacade.php
- app/models/services/reminder/ReminderService.php
- app/models/services/reminder/ReminderServiceServiceProvider.php

**We are struck at following error**

```
Illuminate \ Container \ BindingResolutionException 
Target [Repositories\Reminder\ReminderInterface] is not instantiable.
```

Can someone please guide what may be going wrong?

**Our code is exactly the same as in the article.** I tried to be brief in this description as posting code of all 7 classes is not sensible. Please let me know if you need any details.

Comment: Can you edit your question with the code in your app/models/repositories/reminder/ReminderRepositoryServiceProvider.php

Answer (score 5):

### Option 1

You might be missing a binding:

```
App::bind('Repositories\Reminder\ReminderInterface', 'Repositories\Reminder\ReminderRepository');
```

If you don't tell Laravel which implementation of your Interface you need it to Instantiate it will try to instantiate ReminderInterface, which is not instantiable, as the error says.

### Option 2

If you are binding it in your service provider, you have to make sure your service provider is being executed, by adding it to `app/config/app.php`?

Comment: ReminderRepositoryServiceProvider has following code : $this->app->bind( 'Repositories\Reminder\ReminderInterface', function($app) 
         { 
             return new ReminderRepository(new Reminder()); 
         });  We think above code is doing what you suggested.. ? we also tried using App::bind in global.php but still doesn't work

Comment: So you are binding it. But is this being called? Did you added your service provider to your app/config/app.php?

Comment: yes we added service provider in app.php & alias for ReminderFacade